# A datatable column can't be of type oraclelob

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, blob

Can I have a datatable column of type OracleLOB, the same way I can declare a column to be of type byte array?

**Update:** Is it possible to convert `byte[]` into OracleLOB, as Oracle LOB can be converted into `byte[]` in `Read()` method.

Comment: [This example explain](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_orablobs.html) in great detail how to work with oraclelob column.

Comment: That link was informative, but @Steve pls take a look at the update

Answer (score 2):

No, a DataTable's [`DataColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8a7cyy8d) supports following DataTypes:

1. Boolean
2. Byte
3. Char
4. DateTime
5. Decimal
6. Double
7. Int16
8. Int32
9. Int64
10. SByte
11. Single
12. String
13. TimeSpan
14. UInt16
15. UInt32
16. UInt64
17. Byte[]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype.aspx

Comment: Can I convert a byte array into an OracleLOB?

Comment: AFAIK you can only load it from database. http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/articles/lob.html (i haven't used oracle for ages)

Comment: Yep, if all I have a byte array and I want to convert into OracleLOB, issue arises. Thanks for the answer